# CRON to run every 15 minutes for one week?

Tags: cron, centos6.4

How do I create a CRON job so that it runs every 15 minutes (24 hours a day) but for one week only and exits? Thanks!

Comment: First make a cron job to run it every 15 minutes. Second make a cron job that runs in one week and removes both cron jobs.

Answer (score 7):

Cron has no concept of week, you will have to have your script or some other script make the final decision on whether to run or not. The [date](http://linux.die.net/man/1/date) command can provide the ISO week of year %V so you could do something like

```
*/15 * * * * test `date +\%V` == "30" &&  doSomething
```

to run a script doSomething every 15 minutes next week but it would run next year too so use

```
*/15 * * * * test `date +\%G\%V` == "201330" &&  doSomething
```

to limit it to this year.

Note that the `%`'s above are escaped with a `\` it is important.

Comment: What happen if you creat cronjob on Saturday of week 30, then on Monday of week 31, `doSomething` will not run?

Comment: @Gnouc: Correct.

Comment: @Edward wants cronjob run for a week, I think it means 7 days.

Comment: @Gnouc: How do you know that you're a mind reader ? I provided a method which is generally extensible. As I'm sure you know the date command is very flexible Edward could use ...+%s having pre calculated the correct number of seconds ... once you have a method the rest is easy.